# Typescript: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Pick<T, K>', how do I type javascript `pick` function correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I want to type a function called `pick`, I know typescript has built-in `Pick<T, K>`, now I want to implement the actual source code usage part, but I'm stuck.

What this function do is to `pick` provided `object`'s property based on given strings and return `new object`.

The usage is this:

```
const data = { name: 'Jason', age: 18, isMember: true };
const pickedData = pick(data, ['name', 'isMember']);

console.log(pickedData)
// => { name: 'Jason', isMember: true }
```

My `pick` function's javascript implementation `without typescript` is this:

```
function pick(obj, properties) {
  let result = {}

  properties.forEach(property => {
    result[property] = obj[property];
  });

  return result;
}
```

Here is the `typescript` version, but it's not compiling:

```js
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, properties: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  let result: Pick<T, K> = {}; // Typescript yells: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Pick<T, K>'.

  properties.forEach(property => {
    result[property] = obj[property];
  });

  return result;
}
```

My VSCode screenshot:

[image]

But, there is one solution, I don't know if this is a `good` solution, that is to add `as Pick<T, K>`:

```js
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, properties: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  let result: Pick<T, K> = {} as Pick<T, K> ; // Typescript now satisfy with this.

  properties.forEach(property => {
    result[property] = obj[property];
  });

  return result;
}
```

However, when using this `pick` function, `typescript` doesn't show the picked object property, instead, it shows unnecessary information:

[image]

It shows me this:

```js
// typescript shows me, not what I want.
const pickedData: Pick<{
    name: string;
    age: number;
    isMember: boolean;
}, "name" | "isMember">
```

Is there any way that `typescript` can show me this?

```js
// This is what I want typescript to show me.
const pickedData: {
  name: string;
  isMember: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Titian's answer IS the answer. Right? Titian's answer frequently is. BUT if you've ended up at this post for similar if slightly different, probably less complex, reasons you might like to know that something as simple as `Partial<Pick<T, K>>` might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that `{}` should not be assignable to `Pick<T, K>` since `Pick<T, K>` will probably have required properties. There are some instances where a type assertion is the only way to get things to work and this is one of those. Typescript does not know that you plan to assign those properties a bit later, you have that information and provide it to the compiler in the form of the type assertion, basically saying, relax, I know this isn't really `Pick<T, K>` but I will make it into that shortly.

The second part of you issue is not so much a functional one `Pick<{ name: string; age: number; isMember: boolean;, "name" | "isMember">` is structurally equivalent to `{ name: string; isMember: boolean; }`. Sometimes the language service expands these types, sometimes it does not. This is a recent [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30312) describing this exact behavior.

You can force an expansion of the type with a more complicated type (an identity mapped type in an intersection with `{}`):

```
type Id<T extends object> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, properties: K[]): Id<Pick<T, K>> {
  let result: Pick<T, K> = {} as Pick<T, K> ; // Typescript now satisfy with this.

  properties.forEach(property => {
    result[property] = obj[property];
  });

  return result;
}

const data = { name: 'Jason', age: 18, isMember: true };
const pickedData = pick(data, ['name', 'isMember']);

console.log(pickedData)
```

Just as a warning, there are no guarantees `Id` will always be expanded, all I can say is that in the current version `Id` seems to always force the expansion of the mapped type.